# "A constant value is expected" error when adding values to PointF array inside for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

im a newbie in C# programming. I having difficulties with my project. Here is the thing.
- I have a list of **MCvBox2dD** name **lstRectangles**
- I want to get the center of each box and place it all on **PointF** array named center.

here is my code:

```
        List<MCvBox2D> lstRectangles; // stores data of detected boxes
        ...

        int size = lstRectangles.Count(); //total boxes detected
        PointF[] center = null; //array of PointF where I want to transfer the center of each detected boxes

        for (int j = 0; j < lstRectangles.Count(); j++) 
        {
            center = new PointF[j] // here is the error, "A constant value is expected"
            {
                new PointF(lstRectangles[j].center.X , lstRectangles[j].center.Y)
            };

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to declare the size for your array of PointF (equals to the lstRectangle elements)
Then the correct syntax to add a new PointF to the array is the following

```
    int size = lstRectangles.Count(); 
    PointF[] center = new PointF[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < lstRectangles.Count(); j++) 
    {
        center[j] = new PointF(lstRectangles[j].center.X , lstRectangles[j].center.Y)
    }
```

However, instead of using an array, I suggest to use a `List<PointF>`

```
    List<PointF> center = new List<PointF>();
    foreach(MCvBox2D box in lstRectangles) 
    {
        center.Add(new PointF(box.center.X , box.center.Y));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mr. @steve, i just solved my problem. Using both of your codes, maybe the error was not setting the size of my array. I also used the List array instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help, since you are a new user on SO I wish to remember that, if you find useful answers, you could show your appreciation upvoting the best ones and accepting the one that worked for you [See Help here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you've both specified an exact size of the array and the set of elements that make up the array.  C# has to pick one of these values to use as the size of the array.  In this case `j` is not a constant hence it can't validate that these two numbers match up and it's issuing an error.

To fix this just remove the size argument and let C# infer the size based on the number of elements you use

```
center = new PointF[]
{
  new PointF(lstRectangles[j].center.X , lstRectangles[j].center.Y)
};
```

Based on the context though it looks like what you're really trying to do is assign a new `PointF` into the array at `j`.  If so then do the following

```
center[j] = new PointF(lstRectangles[j].center.X , lstRectangles[j].center.Y);
```

Comment: I already tried the second code you gave before, and it gives me "object reference not set to an instance of an ojbect" error. but thanks for the fast reply

Comment: @julianconcepcion that's a runtime issue vs. a compile time issue though so at least the code is running now.  The most likely cause of this error is `lstRectangles[j].center` being a `null` value.  Have you verified that the field is being initilaized properly.

Comment: Yes, i tried this code to check whether it contains something **"textBox1.text = lstRectangles[j].center;"** and also this to verify if the x and y coordinates of **lstRectangles[j].center** are the same **"textBox2.text = lstRectangles[j].center.X , textBox3.text = lstRectangles[j].center.Y"**.

Comment: @julianconcepcion try attaching a debugger and see what exactly is `null` here.  This is something that we can't deduce from the code sample.  Have to actually run it and see

Comment: but it isn't inside the for-loop when i tried that codes, so i wonder if it is inside the loop that makes the **lstRectangles.center** null

Comment: Sir, i just solved my problem using the code of Mr. steve, maybe the problem was that I wasn't able to set the size of the **PointF** array at all. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks